# tmLanguage syntax highlighting with begin-end rules without highlighting a begin that doesn't have an end

Tags: syntax-highlighting, tmlanguage

I am creating a simple postfix programming language. The syntax is as follows:
`2 3 add` adds the two integers `2` and `3` together. `"hello, world!" puts` puts the string `"hello, world!"` to STDOUT.

The defining of new functions that can be used, is done as follows:

```
"fourth_pow"
  "This function raises the argument on the top of the stack to the fourth power."
  [
    dup dup dup mul mul mul
  ]
def
```

Whitespace and newlines are not important in the language grammar. This means that above definition could also have been made as `"fourth_pow" "..." [ dup dup dup mul mul mul] def` (but of course, this is less readable).

I now want to highlight the syntax of this language, such that in a definition statement as above, the newly defined function name and the `def` keyword are highlighted.

A snippet from the `.tmLanguage` file (in YAML-format) is:

```
definition:
    name: "entity.other.function.jux-beta_syntax"
    begin: ("([a-zA-Z_][\w]*[?!]?)")
    end: (def)
    beginCaptures:
      '1': {name: "entity.name.function.jux-beta_syntax"}
    contentName: "support.constant.jux-beta_syntax"
    patterns:
    - include: '#comment'
    - include: '#quotation_start'
    - include: '#quotation_end'
    - include: '#string'
    - include: '#identifier'
    - include: '#integer'
```

(See the whole file [here](https://gist.github.com/Qqwy/a60585bb3fdddf748dd2ac8b06d27dac))

This 'works', but it means that when at the end of the file, I start a new string, it is highlighted as if it would be a function definition. This because the 'begin' part of the `#definition` rule matches. But what I want to happen, is to only colour it if the match could be closed.

Is there a way to do so using the tmLanguage format?

Answer (score 1):

The major problem is that, at least in Sublime Text (I haven't tested TextMate or VSCode), the regex engine can only match one line at a time using `.tmLanguage` files. Therefore, something like this:

```
(?m:("([a-zA-Z_][\w]*[?!]?)")(.*)(def))
```

using the `?m:` multiline option (`.` matches newlines) won't work, although it works just fine in Ruby (the regex engine is based on Oniguruma). Because syntax highlighting only goes one line at a time, your `beginCaptures` matches as soon as a double-quoted string is entered. Of course, once the body of the function and `def` are written, everything highlights appropriately.

Unfortunately, I'm not fluent enough in it to give you a relevant working example, but you may want to check out the new [`sublime-syntax`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) format in the most recent versions of [Sublime Text 3](https://sublimetext.com/3). It functions using a stack, so you can push and pop contexts, allowing for matching on multiple lines. In the Selected Examples section, look at Bracket Balancing as an example - it highlights closing parentheses `)` without a matching opening paren `(`.

Good luck!